# Schedule mongo db agenda in lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks

I want to be able to set status of a booking status from 'active' to 'inactive' 5 minutes after the seat has been selected in **Mongo DB**.

In EC2 we used npm package agenda with mongodb to change data in certain time . how can we do it in lambda?(create one time trigger)).

So far I have tried to work with mongodb stich but they only supported CRON jobs not trigger that is created certain time after the data is inserted.

Comment: Please explain what have you tried so far. Your question doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create CRON based rule in EventBridge that will trigger your Lambda.